# Algebraic ellipsoidal least squares fit

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods

I'm looking to perform a least squares fit in 3D to a quadratic surface of the form: 
\begin{equation}
Ax^2 + Bxy + Cxz + Dy^2 + Eyz + Fz^2 + ax + by + cz + d = 0
\end{equation}
by minimizing
\begin{equation}
\delta \sum_i \left( Ax_i^2 + Bx_iy_i + Cx_iz_i + Dy_i^2 + Ey_iz_i + Fz_i^2 + ax_i + by_i + cz_i + d \right)^2 = 0
\end{equation}
where $i$ runs over the data points. This can be easily achieved by solving the resulting coupled linear equations.

Now, if I wanted an ellipsoid-specific fit, I would have to constrain the first 6 parameters to form a symmetric, definite matrix $M$ (either positive or negative definite) of the form: 
\begin{equation}
M = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
A & B/2 & C/2 \\
B/2 & D & E/2 \\
C/2 & E/2 & F
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}
Does anyone know a nice scheme to incorporate this positive definite constraint in computational code? I don't want to use Lagrange multipliers because for a $3\times3$ matrix this would mean the calculation of the determinant and the principal minors, thereby making the constraint equation nonlinear in the parameters. I can do this exact same thing easily for the 2D ellipse, but the math seems to become much more complicated for 3D. I'd appreciate any insight into this problem.
 Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your algorithm for the case of ellipses? I'm curious how you achieve a linear fit without the Lagrange multipliers.